# Cannot render correct URL for my MVC Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

Just starting to delve into route `Areas`. I'm attempting some basic stuff first before I get fancy.  When I type the physical route into the address bar it works great.  However, when I try to use `@Url.Action` or `@Html.ActionLink` to create a link MVC cannot figure out how to calculate the correct route.

**TYPING THIS WORKS:**
So, I know the routes are setup correctly...

```
http://localhost:51515/intro/tutorials/one
```

**MY CONTROLLER LOOKS LIKE:**
Again, this resolves correctly when I type it into the address bar...

```
[RouteArea("intro")]
[RoutePrefix("tutorials")]
[Route("{action}")]
public class IntroTutorialsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult One()
    {
        var path = @"~/Views/tutorials/intro/one.cshtml";
        return View(path);
    }
}
```

**MY SAD ATTEMPTS AT THE URL:**
Obviously, the problem is here...

```
@Html.ActionLink("intro", "one", "tutorials", new { Area = "intro" }, null)
<a href="@Url.Action("one", "tutorials", new { Area = "intro" })">One</a>
```

These resolve nothing and/or nonsense...

**ON A SIDE-NOTE:**
If I `hand-type` the url's into the link...they work.

For example:

- href="/intro/tutorials/one"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to have to answer my own question...

Apparently, the `Html.ActionLink` and `Url.Action` commands do not consider any attribute prefixing you may have put atop your controllers.  As such, you must still input your action & controller name in the normal format...THEN...add-in your `area`.

**THIS WORKED FOR ME...**

```
@Url.Action("one", "introtutorials", new { Area = "intro" })
```